# How to make the webpage take up the whole screen.

Tags: html, css

I was just wondering how to make webpages like [zavee.com](http://zavee.com) take up the whole screen rather than just in the box, like how groupon can make it look like it takes up the whole screen. Also any other help on making it look more modern? I’m a beginner coder, and I am just testing out how to make websites look better with inspect element or downloading the files, so one day I could maybe make my own website.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. Try learning HTML and CSS here: http://www.codecademy.com/ , try to create something simple and then post more specific questions.

Comment: I completed all of the courses for html, css, and javascript there, I was just wondering how groupon did it

Comment: This is much too broad, but most of your problems can be solved with `width: 100%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking up the whole width of the page is a matter of responsive design. For example, you could operate in vw (view width) instead of pixels. A div with 100vw (one hundred view width) is taking the whole width of the screen, 50vw - half of the width etc.

Comment: Thanks! I never new this, this actually helped me a LOT!

Comment: Any way to make it so one can scroll horizontally just in case they have an extremely small window or have two windows side by side or something like that?

Comment: You should read about responsive design and media queries. The approach is not to scroll horizontally, but to make the content behave in different ways depending on the width of the device (phone, tablet etc.). For example, if you have 3 divs one next to another, each 33.33vw on a laptop, you could make them appear one under another, each 100vw, if you're using a small device. Google "responsive design" and there you go, the journey begins!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the page in the full mode you should find the div wrapper that contains the whole page and assigning the `width` to `100%`.

For example: `#wrapper {width:100%;}`

Answer (score 0):

Either use f11 I think it is, or you can swap browsers, because on chrome for me that looks exactly the same as stackoverflow right here.